# Mars Eclipse - branches are the same

Tags: eclipse, git, branch, eclipse-mars

I downloaded and installed the Mars Eclipse a couple days ago.

When I was working on branches, I've noticed that they are the same...

This is what I'm doing:
I create a new branch "test" and change some files in it. When I switch to branch "master" files are the same like in branch "test".

Does anyone know how to fix it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added and committed the changes to your branch, and the files look the same in Eclipse, you just need to refresh your view using F5 or right click on your project and hit 'Refresh'.

If you did not add and commit your changes, then the given behavior is expected.